# Finding customers who have made an order within 30 days

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of customers and order dates, I want to find the customers who have made at least two orders within 30 days.

For instance if Customer 12 orders on the one product on 20/06/2013 and makes another order on 01/07/2013. I want the query to bring back Customer 12

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried any query ?

Comment: Within 30 days of each other or within 30 days from now?

Comment: within 30 days of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you need using a self join. You may want to index whatever the customer identifier is (in this case `customer_name`)

```
SELECT DISTINCT o1.customer_name
FROM orders o1
JOIN orders o2
  ON o1.customer_name = o2.customer_name
 AND o1.id <> o2.id 
 AND ABS(DATEDIFF(day, o1.order_date, o2.order_date)) < 30
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ab37/1).

If you're running SQL Server 2012, this may (should) give better performance;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT customer_name, order_date od1,
       LAG(order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY order_date) od2
  FROM orders
)
SELECT DISTINCT customer_name 
FROM cte
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, od2, od1) < 30
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ab37/6).

Comment: It seems to be working, I also have a website source, I want to know if the customer ordered from the same site, with the same conditions, for instance Customer 12 ordered from website 50, 2 times within 30 days. Can I add a where clause to the first answer you gave? Thanks again, sorry new to this.

Comment: @Woodington Should work to just add `AND o1.site = o2.site` and similar for the conditions. I guess you may want to also select o1.site and o1.conditions to the field list to get them as a result.

Comment: I have to Source IDs I'm looking for, I want to filter the others out, I added where a.source_id in (1,6) to the very end but this isn't working properly.

Comment: @Woodington I'm not sure I understand your new problem, maybe something like `SELECT DISTINCT o1.customer_name
FROM orders o1
JOIN orders o2
  ON o1.customer_name = o2.customer_name AND o1.source_id=o2.source_id  AND o1.id <> o2.id 
 AND ABS(DATEDIFF(day, o1.order_date, o2.order_date)) < 30 WHERE o1.source_id IN (1,6)
`? If not, you may need to add some details to your question, or start a new question with the new details (tends to get more attention when it's on the start page)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    customerid,
    count(*) 
FROM
    orderTable 
WHERE 
    orderDate between <startDate> and <endDate>
GROUP BY 
    customerid 
HAVING 
     count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, but is there a way of doing it without a date range, I have a large amount of dates spanning years and want to see what customers returned within 30 days throughout the whole data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    customer_name, 
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN datediff( dd, order_date, getdate() ) 
            <=30 THEN 1 
        END
    ) AS order_count   
FROM 
    order_table 
GROUP BY 
    customer_name
```